# Email Paths / Forwarding

Tags: domain-name, exchange-migration

I have just registered a domain name and want to forward emails that are sent to this domain name to an Exchange Server that I am building.

I don't know a terrible lot about the process of how I setup everything to push into an Exchange environment, and was hoping someone could help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details will depend on who you registered the name with and what tools they provide you for setting up DNS records.

Roughly:

- you'll need to have a routable IP address for the Exchange Server
- you'll need to set up a DNS "A" record that says "the IP address of the server named mail.mydomain.com is 123.123.123.123"
- you'll need to set up a DNS "MX" record that says "email for mydomain.com goes to the server mail.mydomain.com"

It seems to me I've seen similar questions before... you might want to search for more questions and answers on A and MX records.

Comment: So the IP address where my exchange server will be located needs to have a static IP?

Comment: It's much much *much* better if it's static, but there are ways to deal with having a dynamic address.

Comment: A high rep user here (Justin Scott) runs DtDNS, a service that allows a domain to be hosted at a location with dynamic/changing IP address.  Go to dtdns.com FAQ for more info.  
--> http://serverfault.com/users/671/justin-scott